# Trying to update SQLite in Rails without creating duplicate data

Tags: rails-activerecord, unique-constraint

I don't really know the appropriate language to ask this question; however I am trying to update a my rails SQLite database with and keep the values unique. So I don't want to create duplicate values. My table has a column "X" and for column "X" only one field value of 10,20,30, or 40.  however all can have the value 0. These are no polymorphic assignment in my code.

I had attempted to use a helper clear out all the values of 10s before assigning a new values of 10 the field being updated.

Helper

```
 def clear_then_assign(number)
    Gallery.where(UserCode: current_user.code).rewhere( SPCode: number).each do |nix|
    nix.SPCode = nil
    end
```

return(number)
   end

inline code:

```
<% if current_user.Admin == true %>
 <label for="spread">Photo Spread:</label>
    <br><%= f.radio_button :SPCode,  clear_then_assign(10),  :checked => false %> Lead
    <br><%= f.radio_button :SPCode, 20,  :checked => false %> Pic 2
    <br><%= f.radio_button :SPCode, 30,  :checked => false %> Pic 3
    <br><%= f.radio_button :SPCode, 40,  :checked => false %> Editorial
    <br><%= f.radio_button :SPCode, 'nil', :checked => false %> NONE
<% end %>
```

This doesn't give me an error, but it does absolutely nothing. Any suggestions.

Comment: Just curious, does anyone get what I was trying to say here?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I wasn't using save now my code reads:

```
 def clear_then_assign(number)


    Gallery.where(UserCode: current_user.code).rewhere( SPCode: number).each do |nix|
      nix.SPCode = 0
      nix.save
    end
```

return(number)
   end